# How long will it takes a cardano node to fully sync?

Tags: cardano-node

I have startted my cardano node with this command.

```
cardano-node run \
--config $HOME/cardano/testnet-config.json \
--database-path $HOME/cardano/db/ \
--socket-path $HOME/cardano/db/node.socket \
--host-addr 127.0.0.1 \
--port 1337 \
--topology $HOME/cardano/testnet-topology.json
```

Now what i can see in my terminal is this.

```
dk-Latit:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:142] [2022-02-15 08:42:59.71 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: 4ec48842a96990c32bcc0bb3fa99037d12c70228df6a57bec7e273c9fb5789f8 at slot 45502922
[dk-Latit:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:142] [2022-02-15 08:43:01.05 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: 001df73cc6c3f531d4bb304ec579ccf4323811aa9f2404865684fa65554c3bfd at slot 45503205
[dk-Latit:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:142] [2022-02-15 08:43:03.18 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: 601a92bdbbc85fd99b8108780419b9716ce74379ad39dffed21d8753cc3d067f at slot 45503277
[dk-Latit:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:142] [2022-02-15 08:43:04.53 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: ffe4eeeb00529dbf0b031f6822c33dc3c93c68c02c22b01f709c2f3cf6cd7e44 at slot 45503504
[dk-Latit:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:1
```

How long am i supposed to see this? Is there any way to check whether the node is fully synced or not or what percentage its got synced?

Comment: When you accept an answer, you should also up-vote it.  ;-)  Let's build this community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testnet should sync within a couple of hours. Mainnet will be longer (I have not done this recently so I do not know).

There is a `cardano-cli query tip` command. eg:

```
CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=state-node-mainnet/node.socket ./cardano-cli query tip --cardano-mode --mainnet
{
    "epoch": 321,
    "hash": "561310c715bff5d8a8f310e55e3ceb5b9116a058aaf716e3ab930bc120c6e47e",
    "slot": 53350023,
    "block": 6884753,
    "era": "Alonzo",
    "syncProgress": "100.00"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of early 2022, I would expect about two days.

Comment: is that same for testnet as well?

Comment: for testnet, it typically takes 4-6 hours depending upon your internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

It took about half a day to a day, from my personal experience in early 2022. But I think it varies depending on internet connection and the computer.

Make sure your machine is not resource-starved. I.e. check that you have enough RAM as you sync. While cardano-node does not require a super powerful computer, any computer process would struggle to get any work done if there are not enough resources ;)